# How to make an if statement works only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I've made a simple if statement in Python 3 that checks if there's a specific word inside a line and if so it changes the value of the phrase. In the example below I'm showing you the code for the comma.
Problem is that I need this statement to apply only once per line and I'm getting mad while trying to implement it.

That's the code

```
temp1 = ""
for line in testo.splitlines():
    n = len(line)
    if len(line) > 0:
        line = line[0].upper()+line[1:]
    if n >= 30 and ', ' in line and line.find(', ') >= 20:
        line = re.sub(', ', '\n', line)

    temp1 += line + "\n"
testo = temp1
```

This is the phrase

```
Let me see your hard work, come on, work harder
```

At the moment the code split the phrase like this

```
Let me see your hard work
Come on
Work harder
```

What I wish to happen is to have the phrase splitted this way (the if statement applies only once)

```
Let me see your hard work
Come on, work harder
```

Thank you everybody!

Comment: change that second `if` to `elif` so it is skipped if the first if succeeds.

Comment: Have you tried Keeping a flag, which would be false initially. After first if make it true and once it's true no need to execute the first if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` has a count parameter that allows you to specify a maximum number of substitutions. Try `re.sub(', ', '\n', line, count=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but if you add a break statement after you substitute the new line for the comma, it should exit the loop after splitting the text only once.

```
if n >= 30 and ', ' in line and line.find(', ') >= 20:
    line = re.sub(', ', '\n', line)
    break
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: I tried break but I have others if statements after this one so it wasn't an option. Steele Farnsworth provided the correct answer tho :)

Answer (score 0):

This breaks out the line splitting logic into it's own function for clarity, returning a list of lines.  With the list you can re-add the line breaks as desired.

```
phrase = "Let me see your hard work, come on, work harder"

MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 30

SPLIT_CHARS = ', '
SPLIT_CHARS_LENGTH = 19

def split_line(line) -> list:
    result = [line]
    if len(line) > MAX_LINE_LENGTH and SPLIT_CHARS in phrase[SPLIT_CHARS_LENGTH:]:
        split_index = SPLIT_CHARS_LENGTH + phrase[19:].find(SPLIT_CHARS)
        initial = line[:split_index]
        remaining = line[split_index + len(SPLIT_CHARS):].capitalize()
        result = [initial, remaining]
    return result

for line in testo.splitlines():
    parts = split_line(line)
    new_lines = "\n".join(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
finished = False

if condition and not finished:
    do_something()
    finished = True
```